# ¿Cómo borrar una linea especifica de un archivo usado por mi herramienta de automatización?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Estoy creando una herramienta de automatización con el modulo `pyautogui`, a partir de argumentos ejecuto ciertos comando que realizan las tareas.

El comando que muestro a continuación abre mi navegador, escribe una url que se encuentra en un fichero txt y la busca. La situación es que al escribir la url y ejecutarla el comando debe eliminar la linea que escribió del fichero tal que así:

> https:/\www.stackoverflow.com/
>   https:/\www.stackoverflow.com/
>   https:/\www.stackoverflow.com/

Al abrir el fichero y escribir la primera url, debe quedar:

> https:/\www.stackoverflow.com/
>   https:/\www.stackoverflow.com/

Agradezco su ayuda y explicación. Éste es el código relevante:

```
class Automatizar():
    def escribir(self):
...........................
for e in len(sys.argv):

    elif sys.argv[e+1] == "--u":
         os.system("start chrome.exe")
         with open(sys.argv[e+1],'r') as file:
              P.typewrite(file.readline(), 0.5)
              P.press("ENTER")
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes eliminar contenido de un archivo de texto directamente a no ser que sea al final del mismo, y en estos casos con codificaciones en las que los caracteres tienen un tamaño variable como UTF-8 hay que tener cuidado con que se trunca al final.

Si tu archivo no es muy extenso, como supongo por el uso que le das, cargarlo en memoria no es un problema. Una posibilidad es abrir el archivo en modo `r+` (lectura con posibilidad de escritura). Como `readline` consume la línea del iterador, basta con que muevas el cursor del archivo al inicio, lo trunques y escribas lo que quedaba por leer (previamente almacenado en una variable usando `read`).

```
with open(sys.argv[e+1],'r+') as file:
    P.typewrite(file.readline(), 0.5)
    P.press("ENTER")
    resto = file.read()
    file.seek(0)
    file.truncate()
    file.write(resto)
```

Comment: gracias, buen hombre